# How to get rid of Ignorance?

Tags: pratityasamutpada, ignorance

According to dependent origination , ignorance is at the root of suffering.

What are the various ways in which we can get rid of ignorance?

Answer (score 1):

Ignorance of what? Ignorance of the reality of phenomenon. Ignorance of the fact that how things appear are not the way they are. What is ignorance? Opposite of knowledge, opposite of wisdom. How to counter ignorance? With the right knowledge- wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Study/read the Teachings.

Thoroughly examine & rationalize (yoniso manasikara) the Teachings, so they make sense.

Verify the subject of the Teachings in meditation with direct insight.

Comment: Cessation of Ignorance is Nibbana … I haven’t met anyone who has achieved Nibbana… Ignorance is deeply rooted.

Comment: DN 16 says when the noble eightfold path is practice correctly, the world will not be devoid of arahants.

Comment: Excellent point of view. Thanks.